# Best search technologies for .NET faceted results with calculated fields

Tags: .net, search, solr, lucene.net, faceted-search

I am developing a search app that needs to return faceted results depending on certain criteria. Some of the criteria are used for calculating computed fields which should also be filtered on.

The applicable calculations are business logic which are driven from code inside the domain layer.

Currently I've developed my own search mechanism which is working quite well, but it  slows down over bigger data sets. What are my options in implementing a third party search like Lucene or Solr in .NET that will fit my use case?

All the examples I've seen so far are filtering results based on static fields instead of dynamically calculated fields.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think Lucene is the solution to filtering on computed fields.  Post specifics of your data and search.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I don't, hence my question. I want the best solution for doing facetable results on computed fields. Hope I make sense now?

Comment: Need specifics of the data sets and search.  You have also have SQL and NoSQL.   What is bigger?  A thousand?  A billion?

Comment: to give you an idea, it should work similar as this site http://directlease.nl/DLNl/home.do